# SC-IM: failure during install

Tags: make, github

using: ubuntu 18.04 and git version 2.17.1

when i try to install SC-IM as per the instructions for ubuntu: https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im/wiki/Ubuntu-with-XLSX-import-&-export

i see 'undefined reference' when i run `make`, as follows:

```
[...]/sc-im/src/tui.c:1535: undefined reference to `init_extended_pair'
color.o: In function `redefine_color':
[...]/sc-im/src/color.c:594: undefined reference to `init_extended_color'
color.o: In function `define_color':
[...]/sc-im/src/color.c:661: undefined reference to `init_extended_color'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:194: recipe for target 'sc-im' failed
make: *** [sc-im] Error 1
```

then when i run `sudo make install` i see:

```
install -d /usr/local/bin
install sc-im /usr/local/bin/sc-im
install: cannot stat 'sc-im': No such file or directory
Makefile:178: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

they say here: https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im/issues/253 "try linking against ncursesw", and then: "That solved it." But what does this mean? I googled and didnt find anything useful. Thanks.

edit: Maybe this is relevant?: https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04.1-with-libxlsreader I added these 3 lines to the `Makefile` in sc-im/src but it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `undefined reference to 'init_extended_pair'` error, compile with the `ncursesw` library instead of `ncurses`.

Answer (score -1):

i found a solution in this discussion: "Segfault when using wrong number separator #482" https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im/issues/482

referring to the `init_extended_color` error (above) the author of SC-IM says: "the version of ncurses you have [doesn't] have that function defined. You might need version 6.2 or just replace the two `init_extended_color` calls on `color.c` with `init_color` (lines 580 and 642)"

when i try to install `libncurses5-dev` and `libncursesw5-dev` ubuntu suggests i have the latest version , but if i look in /usr/include/ncurses.h it shows version 6.1

therefore I must change `init_extended` to `init` as he suggests, specifically I changed `init_extended_color` to `init_color` in `color.c` (in two places) and `init_extended_pair` to `init_pair` in `tui.c`, then it compiles just fine